# Web scraping(selenium) - filling a pop-up using code

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i am scraping a page using python which has multiple clicks, so i used selenium. i get a pop up in which i have to enter some details and then i can proceed. Can anyone tell me how to fill it using code?

The link for the page is: http://www.sky.com/skyq/buy/build
When you try to add the "SKY broadband", you have to check availibilty where you need to fill some details.
Here's my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Nishima.Suman\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (3)\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.sky.com/shop/beta?s_tnt=87085:31:0');
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/article/a""").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="dsl-check"]""").click()
```

I am unable to proceed ahead.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code service. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself. After which, if you're still having trouble, post your attempt so we can help you. I had a look at the page and your description doesn't adequately describe the problem anyway.

Comment: Whey don't you try record and play tool in the firefox browser and export it to java code and check yourself what code it generates. Based on that you can write your own code. [More info here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-ide/record-and-playback-selenium-ide-test-case/)

Comment: @ChickenFeet, i am not asking for code. I am just asking if there is a package or library to do so..:)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by check availability and filling out details? The Selenium web-driver provides functionality for filling out forms, clicking buttons etc, so based on your question description, Selenium can do the job. Please update your question and elaborate on the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: I actually didn't know that selenium was able to do so. I found the solution. Thanx!